# Javascript validations

Tags: javascript, validation

form validation

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href ="home.css">
    <script src ="contact.js"></script> 
    <title>Barber</title>   
</head>
<body> 
    <script src ="contact.js"></script> 
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="barber.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Gallery.html"> Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="Appointment.html">Appointment (php) </a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href ="Contact.html"> Contact Us (javascript)</a></li>    
        <li><a href="LogIn.html">Log In(php, java, sql) </a></li>    
    </ul>
    <li2>
         <h2>Contact Us:</h2>         
    </li2>
    <div>
     <form name= "form" method "post"  onsubmit="return validateForm()"  > 
        Name: <input type="text" id= "name" name= "name"/>
        <br>

        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email"     placeholder="JohnDoe@example.com" /> 
        <br> 

        <label for="website">Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone" placeholder="###-###-####" />
        <br>

        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea name="message" id='message' cols="40" rows="6"> 
        </textarea>
        <br>

        <input type ="submit" name="submit" value = "submit" > 
      </form>
     </div>   
   </body>
 </html>
```

external javascript

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">


function validateForm(){

    if (document.form.name.value=="") {
        alert("Empty");
    }
    return;

}
   </script>
```

So I'm trying to validate all of my fields using JavaScript, I am unable to get it to work at all and I've been doing this all day. I had started out with more script than this but it didn't work. So I got rid of it. I think if I can figure out how to validate one field, I should be able to figure out the rest. Can anyone help me out with this?

Also where to I put the external link for my script?

Comment: you want to validate all fields !So validating all filed ,Why you valid one field!

Comment: for starters, you can use jquery. Just search "jquery validation" and there would be plenty of tutorials

Comment: @Michelle have you included the external js file, (which contains your validation script)? If not you can include it the same way you did contact.js using '<script src ="validator.js"></script>' if you name the external script as validator.js

Comment: one field so I could see if it worked and I think if i can get one right i can get the others working properly and I wanted to use Javascript because it was required for my validations.... @Kailas I thinks that's the problem I'm not sure if I included it or not, I put the <script scr ="contact.js"></script> between the body... and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you `contact.js`, just include the js functionality, **no need to have the `<script>` tag**

Your contact.js should look something like:

**contact.js**

```
function validateForm(){

    if (document.form.name.value=="") {
        alert("Empty");
    }
    return;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try with this;

Give one common class to all like class="required".

And then write your javascript like below,

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

function validateForm(){    
  if ($(".required").val() == "")
  {
     alert("Empty");
     return false;
  }
  return;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

> return false;

like this.

```
if (document.form.name.value=="")
{
    alert("Empty");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["form"]["value"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Empty");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for single field check.

```
var dataValue = document.getElementById("name").value;

    if (dataValue == "") {
        alert("Empty");
        return false;
    }
```